# Why does Python not Binarize it?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm pretty new to programming Python and I want a binarize this Array.

So my code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np 
import sklearn.preprocessing 
input_data = np.array 
                (([2.1, -1.9, 5.5],
                  [-1.5, 2.4, 3.5],
                  [0.5, -7.9, 5.6],
                  [5.9, 2.3, -5.8])
data_binarized= preprocessing.Binarizer(threshold=0.5).transform(input_data)
print("\nBinarized data:\n", data_binarized)
```

and it still doesnt work, in any way i change it. What can i do to fix it?

Comment: This doesn't look right.  You reference a preprocessing thing, appear to stuff some data into it, and then seem to reference that same preprocessing thing (or perhaps a different one) in the context of an array being created with the same preprocessor.  Perhaps you can break it up into simpler steps?

Comment: Please check your formatting, this code will not run as-is

Comment: I tried to do that and than it just says Ellipsis is not scriptable. So Im pretty confused at this point..

Comment: If you are getting an error, you should include that in your post. If I fix the typos and problems with creation of the array, this code works fine for me and returns the binary array

Comment: It just says this: line 4
    (([2.1, -1.9, 5.5],
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: That error is because that's not how you initialize an array. Please see my answer below, note that the important part is where the parentheses are in relation to the `array` keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input_data = np.array 
                (([2.1, -1.9, 5.5],
                  [-1.5, 2.4, 3.5],
                  [0.5, -7.9, 5.6],
                  [5.9, 2.3, -5.8])
```

Should read

```
input_data = np.array([[2.1, -1.9, 5.5],
                  [-1.5, 2.4, 3.5],
                  [0.5, -7.9, 5.6],
                  [5.9, 2.3, -5.8]])
```

or

```
input_data = np.array(
                  [[2.1, -1.9, 5.5],
                  [-1.5, 2.4, 3.5],
                  [0.5, -7.9, 5.6],
                  [5.9, 2.3, -5.8]])
```

Comment: Ah, right.  That pesky whitespace-sensitivity.

Comment: And correct-bracket-and-paren-sensitivity, but that _may_ be less of a python specific concern